# Macro vs Subroutine

Tags: macros, abap

I'm trying to understand in which cases macro or subroutine is a better idea to use.

For instance, I'm creating a program to parse a huge xml which has hundreds of fields and attribues and I'm defining subroutines and macros to get those nodes, attributes etc. So these subroutines (or macros) are called ***thousands of times***.

Here are example subroutine and macro that I can use;

**MACRO**

```
DEFINE xml_get_code_att_2.
  node = xml_node_iterator->get_next( ).
  while node is not initial.
    if lv_lastchild is not initial and node->get_name( ) eq lv_lastchild.
      xml_node_iterator = xml_node->create_iterator( ).
      exit.
    endif.
    if node->get_name( ) = &1.
      clear: list, nodee.
      list = node->get_attributes( ).
      nodee = list->get_named_item( 'listID' ).
      if nodee is not initial.
        &2 = nodee->get_value( ).
      endif.
    node = xml_node_iterator->get_next( ).
  endwhile.
  if node is initial.
    xml_node_iterator = xml_node->create_iterator( ).
  endif.
END-OF-DEFINITION
```

**SUBROUTINE**

```
FORM xml_get_code_att_2 USING p_name CHANGING p_listid
  node = xml_node_iterator->get_next( ).
  temp = node->get_name( ).
  while node is not initial.
    if lv_lastchild is not initial and node->get_name( ) eq lv_lastchild.
      xml_node_iterator = xml_node->create_iterator( ).
      exit.
    endif.
    if node->get_name( ) = p_name.
      clear: list, nodee.
      list = node->get_attributes( ).
      nodee = list->get_named_item('listID' ).
      if nodee is not initial.
        p_listid = nodee->get_value( ).
      endif.
    endif.
    node = xml_node_iterator->get_next( ).
  endwhile.
  if node is initial.
    xml_node_iterator = xml_node->create_iterator( ).
  endif.
endform.
```

So which one is better to use?

Comment: This article shows a nice example of using macros in a 'sane' way: http://scn.sap.com/community/abap/blog/2012/10/28/use-macros-use-them-wisely

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is important to understand the difference: Macros are processed at compile time while forms (you're probably better of using methods) are processed at runtime.

As for the advice you asked about: Do **not** use macros to structure code. Macros are a pain in the a...natomy to debug. Macros are best used to shorten single instructions or short code snippets without branching or loops. For everything else, use methods (or forms, if you have to).

Also, to parse and process XML, you might want to check the existing frameworks and techniques...

Comment: +1 I cannot stand it when macros contain huge branches of code -  suddenly stop working correctly... The only time imo for them is when you are doing *very* repetitive operations that don't contain anything beyond very basic assignments or maybe an internal table update. Even then I'd seriously consider using a method or sub.

Comment: Thank you @vwegert for the answer, and for responding all my questions. :)

Answer (score 1):

MACROS can not be debugged  -  I would never use MACRos any more. MACROS are some left overs from the former R2 - Host world of SAP.

With macros you can to real ugly things. There is a table trmac where you put macros. You can use these macros in any abap code and drive others gracy if they don't know the TRMAC table. This is realy SAP 80's programming style. Don't do that.